# How to select a polygon covered by another polygon using Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I am using Overlay Shapes with Google Maps API V3 using Google’s Drawing Manager. I basically allow the user to draw a polygon and save it to a database. They can then edit these polygons at will or create new ones.

The issue I am having is that often new polygons will completely cover existing polygons. Then the user cannot select the polygon beneath the latest one.

I wondered if anyone had managed to devise a script that enabled a user to cycle through the selection of every polygon in a potential stack under the mouse cursor (or pointer/finger...)

The attached image illustrates the predicament. Ideally I'd like something like CTRL+Click to select the polygon beneath the currently selected polygon.

No idea how to even approach this and I could not fine any examples in existence.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Stacked Polygon Example]

Comment: what about having an HTML list of your polygons, clicking on each one brings it to the top?

Comment: Many thanks, yes could work... There will be hundreds of these polygons though so I'd prefer to cycle through them by click if at all possible but I will consider this approach. Perhaps if the click point appears in more than one polygon I could pop a modal requesting which polygon to edit and select that way...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using control click to change the z order.

Comment: Many thanks, yes, that's exactly what I do wish to accomplish - I just don't know how to go about it. I'll do some more research thanks. I guess the alternative is to initially set the zIndex to ensure always ensure the smaller zones are on top of the bigger ones thereby making it easy to select all.

Comment: you can change the zIndex accordingly yes, and implement mouse events on polygons. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent